# How to run Instructions/Commands in a Batch File in parallel?

Tags: windows, parallel-processing, cmd, batch-processing

How to run Instructions/Commands in a Batch File in parallel ?

Contents Inside Batch File: Each Line Calls a Process

E.g.

**StartMyDay.Bat**

```
call devenv.exe
call chrome.exe
call communicator.exe
call VirtualBox.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `start` command, but add the paths to the files if needed.

```
start "" devenv.exe
start "" chrome.exe
start "" communicator.exe
start "" VirtualBox.exe
```